# How to set keyboard repeat delay and speed in Ubuntu Gnome 16.10?

Tags: keyboard, settings, ubuntu-gnome

In previous versions I could tweak the keyboard repeat delay and speed by going to Settings → *Keyboard* → *Typing*. Now in Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 (with GNOME 3.20.2) that panel seems to be missing.

How can I configure those settings in this version?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

These settings are under Settings → *Universal Access* → *Typing* → *Repeat Keys*. You have to click the *Repeat Keys* row item, which brings up a pop-up dialog with two settings: *Delay* and *Speed*.

[image]

This works in Ubuntu 17.04 and above.

In older versions of Ubuntu, the Speed setting worked in reverse: the lower the speed, the faster the repeat rate. This is no longer the case.

Comment: But that does not allow you to increase the speed, neither do the `gsettings` commands that used to. Did Gnome remove this?

Comment: Have you clicked on `Repeat keys`? Because a menu appears allowing you to set the speed.

Comment: I have it on, I didn't see the hidden menu, I will try tonight. Hopefully it can still be set through `gsettings`. I wish the Gnome team wouldn't move settings with every release ...

Comment: OK, so apparently my `gsettings` command did successfully set _Delay_ to its lowest setting, and _Speed_ to its highest setting. None the less, the repeat rate is **significantly** slower than it was in past versions of Gnome. Why enforce these arbitrary restrictions?

Comment: @Loque I just checked on Ubuntu 17.04 and it is under `Settings > Universal Access > Typing > Repeat keys`, exactly the same as 16.04. You may want to fix your answer.

Comment: Yeah Ubuntu added another 300 milliseconds to key delay and slowed down the key repeat by about 30 percent.  I fiddled around with the settings, and to make it the same as before, you need roughly 290ms delay and 32 repeats/second to make it same as before.  I see the pythonic John Cleesian methodologies are still in full effect.

Comment: Bad interface change. "Repeat keys" shows just "On". It is more than natural that the user will think that clicking on it will turn it "Off", when in fact it opens a new window! And who would've thought, the configuration we're looking for is right there. Btw, had the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Great UI design. Why would you put keyboard settings in Settings->Keyboard? Haha that'd be stupid! We should hide them in accessibility under what looks like a toggle-button but isn't instead... Edit: Speed is backwards? Oh my god someone *designed* this??

Comment: Please upvote [this bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/79) so the GNOME maintainers understand how unfortunate these design decisions were.

Comment: WHERE IS SETTINGS? It does not exist anymore.

Comment: Speed now seems the opposite of the answer, as in, the higher the speed, the faster the repeat rate. (3 months ago when I installed on a different machine, speed was indeed backward)

Comment: @mathtick press the windows key (or the command key if you have a mac keyboard) and type "settings"

Answer (score 56):

On ubuntu 14.04 and up this will survive after reboot:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval 30
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 250
```

Comment: This is much better for portable configurations than settings menu, because you can set the exact values instead of blindly adjusting a slider

Comment: Thanks! And FWIW, this should work on any OS using Gnome.

Comment: What units are those numbers? Seem like `delay` is milliseconds? But `repeat-interval` seems to be frequency (hz)? A higher number repeats the keypress faster. E.g. A value of 50 is faster than 30.

Comment: Yes, repeat interval is hz and delay is milliseconds.

Comment: This is a much better answer

Answer (score 33):

If nothing else works, and if you are using the Xorg (i.e. not Wayland), try running `xset r rate 220 40` from a console.

```
xset r rate <milliseconds_before_repeating> <repetitions_per_second>
```

See `man xset` for more info:

> If the server supports the XFree86-Misc extension, or the XKB
> extension, then a  parameter  of  'rate'  is  accepted  and should  be
> followed  by  zero, one or two numeric values. The first specifies the
> delay before autorepeat starts and the second specifies the repeat
> rate.  In the case that the server supports the XKB extension, the
> delay  is  the  number  of milliseconds  before  autorepeat  starts,
> and the rate is the number of repeats per second.  If the rate or
> delay is not given, it will be set to the default value.

For me, the HID layer got broken in some way and config GUI didn't work, `gsettings` didn't work, only `xset` worked.

This solution however is not persistent - will disappear on restart (unless added to `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: +1 Lubuntu 18.04.2 uses this method instead. See file `~/.config/autostart/LXinput-setup.desktop`

Comment: best solution to my problem, as i'm using a window manger without a desktop environment. this line is very handy.

Comment: perfect, it works everywhere !

Comment: seems not work in U22 anymore:
```
xset r 10 10                                                  
xset:  unknown option run
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Ubuntu 18.04.3 User.... and not a techie. I tried changing the `kdrate` in terminal. I was told it had changed, but it didn't change the slow keyboard input.

This low tech method worked for me:

Go to "Show Applications", where there's an "InputMethod" utility, which has a keyboard as the icon. Open this.... ignore the warnings. Select "Yes" then you are presented with a list of options. The one which worked for me is "auto activate IM with @mark for most locales". You need to reboot your PC/laptop.

Then you can go to "Settings", "Typing", and then click on "repeat keys" and "cursor blinking". Both these options have sliders which you can use to speed up and slow the keyboard and key strokes.

I tried looking at the Keyboard Documentation. I didn't understand it, so I hope this answer works for Ubuntu users like me.

Comment: Hi! I followed your steps but still didn't get those sliders you mention.