# Cannot open calculator app from keyboard calculator button

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, gnome-calculator

If I press the calculator button in my keyboard, the gnome calculator app doesn't appear. I have double checked that the shortcut is ok in the settings app keyboard bindings config pane.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I found that installing the calculator app via apt instead of snap (the default in 18.04) fixed this issue:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```

This has the added benefit of making the calculator launch instantaneously again.

The cause of the problem is a [bug in the gnome-settings-daemon package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1796499), which has been fixed in Ubuntu 18.10 and above. The workaround above remains necessary in 18.04, however.

Comment: Great! It also solved the complete transparency window by having enabled Communitheme!

Comment: Much better! It definitely launches faster now!

Comment: How could they possible break the *Calculator* ? Of all things that may be broken this one should always work on any OS, no matter what... *Imagine being a new person to (Ubuntu) Linux and finding that your calculator simply does not work with no error.*

Comment: @Flatron: there are [even *more* basic things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846030/how-to-set-keyboard-repeat-delay-and-speed-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-10#comment1790171_846035) that they broke in Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Working like a charm, with my Micorsoft keyboard!

Comment: For unknown reasons, I started getting a transparent calculator today in Ubuntu 18.04. No idea what I did. But these two steps restored the calculator to a working state. THANKS

Comment: Great! apt version also comes with dark theme instead snap light only...

Comment: thanks. It made my microsoft wired keyboard 600 work

Comment: Wouhou ! Started to be tired of this bug, really fed up with pressing the Super key then "calcu", then 5 s waiting... You did not save my life, but almost ;-) ! Now Gnome Calculator starts instantly (my keyboard is a Microsoft Natural Comfort Curve 3000).

Comment: Worked for me too :-) but now I wonder why the calculator takes sooo long to launch in windoze ??

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the default shortcut for "Launch Calculator"...

[image: Remove default Calculator shortcut]

and instead add a custom shortcut to run `gnome-calculator`, and assign the <kbd>Calculator</kbd> key to it:

[image: Custom Calculator shortcut]

Comment: In my case shortcut button doesn't respond when I press calculator button. This doesn't also respond when I try to bind already defined shortcut