# Why is gnome-calculator scanning my home directory?

Tags: 18.04, snap, malware, system-monitor, gnome-calculator

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04.1 and have gnome-calculator 3.30.1 installed.  I'm pretty sure that's the one that came bundled with 18.04.

[image]

Every time I launch gnome-calculator the following message is logged in /var/log/kern.log by apparmor:

```
kernel: [10238.459543]
audit: type=1400
audit(1547652310.229:29638):
apparmor="DENIED"
operation="open"
profile="snap.gnome-calculator.gnome-calculator"
name="/home/me/Documents/"
pid=10260
comm="head"
requested_mask="r"
denied_mask="r"
fsuid=1000
ouid=1000
```

Seven additional, identical messages are logged, with the only difference being the directory that gnome-calculator is attempting to access:

```
name="/home/me/Desktop/"
name="/home/me/Downloads/"
name="/home/me/Music/"
name="/home/me/Pictures/"
name="/home/me/Videos/"
name="/home/me/Public/"
name="/home/me/Templates/"
```

My interpretation of the above is that gnome-calculator is attempting to scan the contents of my home directory and AppArmor is preventing it from doing so.

If that's the case, **why is gnome-calculator scanning my home directory**?

Is anyone else seeing the same log messages?  Is gnome-calculator 3.30.1 infected by malware?  Should I be concerned?

Comment: Pretty sure something to do with snappy (pre-installed calculator is a snap application).

Comment: It would seem as though that's got something to do with it.  If I replace the snap version with the apt version the messages stop.  I've got about 10 different snaps installed, though, and only gnome-calculator is scanning my home directory — so there's something different about gnome-calculator.

Comment: The snap version of **gnome-system-monitor** seems to generate AppArmor messages as well.  Not the same type, but given they happen every 6 seconds they have the potential to chew up a large amount of drive space.

Comment: There's some misunderstanding here. The snap of gnome-calculator does not use the `home` interface so it *cannot* access the home directory of the user. The error message you're seeing is a warning that it *cannot* access home. if you replace the snap with a deb you're actually undoing that, and installing a calculator which *can* access your home directory. It's *not* malware, and it's *not* "scanning" your home directory. It's working normally.

Comment: @popey Thanks for the reassurance.  Nonetheless, the log entries are being generated because it is _trying._  Why is a calculator _trying_ to open my Documents, Pictures, Desktop and other directories?

Comment: Not necessarily. Again, try not to jump to conclusions that the calculator is somehow trying to do something nafarious. The snaps use a generic launcher script which does a bunch of stuff which is generic for many snaps. It's likely just setting up those directories so that *if* the application *needs* to access Music, or Pictures, it has the right mounts/links to get to them.

Comment: @popey  Sounds reasonable.  Thanks for that.  I replaced it with the apt version anyway just to get rid of the messages.  Will probably give it another chance the next time I upgrade my OS.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No worries, it seems quite normal.

I installed `gnome-calculator` as a snap. When starting it from the
command line, nothing special happens but when I start it via the GUI
(Activities → Search → Calculator) then I see the same messages as 
you do in `kern.log` about scanning my $HOME.

I again uninstalled the snap and installed the `apt` package instead
with the following commands:

```
# switch from snap to apt:
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```

and the messages do no longer appear.

Plus, I can start `gnome-calculator` by a special key on my keyboard and
it opens far quicker, but that's another cup of tea (see this [related
and interesting post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031673/504066)).

(Btw, I also replaced the snap version of `gnome-system-monitor` with the
apt version because the snap version lists *all* the snap filesystems
while the apt version only lists the "regular" ones. I see no point in
listing dozens of those squashfs filesystems which are all 100 % 
full. It just messes up the display.)