# Ubuntu 20.04; Key repeat setting is reset when bluetooth keyboard is connected

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, bluetooth

### Problem

Hi, I'm struggling with key repeat setting.

It's really annoying that key repeat setting is reset when bluetooth keyboard is connected (every time).

Note that repeat key setting using `gsetting` or `Settings - Universal Access - Repeat Keys` has the same problem.

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

### Configratuion

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Keyboard: HHKB Professional Hybrid

Comment: I have the same problem but it's when I've suspended-resumed. By the way what's the `gsetting` command to change repeat keys? (I could put it as a resume script!)

Comment: @artfulrobot [By doing so](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031070/1157589).
If you know how to resume it automatically, please share the magical way :)

Comment: Make shell script in  `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`. `if [[ "$1" == "post" && "$2" == "suspend" ]] ; then gsettings ... ; gsettings ... ; fi` then this script will run when you open your laptop lid and resume from a suspend.

Comment: @artfulrobot
Thanks a lot. I'll do that. Does any file name work?

+) In my case, similar problem occurs when reconnecting bluetooth keyboard.
Is it the same in your case? Or, do you know how to write a shell script to prevent this?

Comment: filename doesn't matter. I don't know about the bluetooth thing. good luck

Comment: Same problem here with just plain wired keyboard, there [is a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1466) recently closed on Gnome project.

Comment: Same problem though didn't test the `system-sleep` script, running `gsettings` commands manually won't fix it unless I use a different number. For example, if the default setting is `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 150`. Running it again after sleep won't change anything. I have to change it to something else first (e.g. `151`) and then reset it to 150 so that it recognizes the change.